# How send data to the event hub and schedule it to run for every 10 seconds?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub, azure-functions-core-tools

I'm trying to send data to the event hub and to schedule it to run for every 10 seconds.
When I refer to this developer's guide document,
[See the bindings compitablity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference)
It mentions only output bindings not input binding to an azure event hub
[refer to this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixc6W.png)

Comment: what do you want to run?

Comment: He's talking about Azure Functions - by the tags he's using. For Event Hubs the "Input Binding" is the "Trigger". So this is indeed possible. But it's very unclear what you actually are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed achieve this using EventHub and Azure Functions, Events will be sent to the event hub and then you can schedule and trigger an azure function.

[image]

You can have a look at the [`serverless event processing architecture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/serverless/event-processing)

Comment: But it still is shown as from event hub to Azure function, I wanna use the azure function as a producer not as consumer

Comment: what is the requirement for that? you could still send events from Azure function to eventhub you dont need a trigger, just write your logic with the SDK

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is send message to Event Hub, so the [Output Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs#output---python-example) is what you want, you could refer to the link code.

```
import datetime
import logging
import azure.functions as func


def main(timer: func.TimerRequest) -> str:
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    logging.info('Message created at: %s', timestamp)
    return 'Message created at: {}'.format(timestamp)
```

Function.json:

```
{
"type": "eventHub",
"name": "$return",
"eventHubName": "myeventhub",
"connection": "MyEventHubSendAppSetting",
"direction": "out"
}
```

Cause the Event Hub binding Input support is no, then for now you could only process message with Trigger or SDK .

If you want the SDk sample you could refer to this one:[Create a Python script to receive events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-python-get-started-send#create-a-python-script-to-receive-events).

Comment: Thank you for your response, You are saying that now I can only process the message from the event hub using the azure function,[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-python-get-started-send#create-a-python-script-to-receive-events),  the above link shows that, how to send events to the event hub using python, is that not possible with azure functions right now? @George Chen

Comment: Of course you could, you just need to use the SDK and cause your question tag is Python so I paste the Python sample, you could use this code in your function to process message. And you could use output binding to write message or use SDK to write message, in the link it also has SDK sample.